# Jquery - stick div onto an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image as background image of a div. The div has scrolls so user can scroll to see the different parts of the image. Now I want to place a small div at a specific position on the image and it should remain at its original position on the image,even if user scrolls, the div should also scroll with the image.

Comment: Can you share your HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
<style>
.outer {width: 300px; height: 400px; overflow:scroll;}
.inner {background: url('http://www.excel-london.co.uk/media/26705/why-london-hero-shot.jpg') no-repeat; background-size:cover; height: 800px; width: 800px;}
.sticker {background-color: #000; width: 100px; height: 100px; position:relative; left: 600px; top: 600px;}
</style>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="sticker">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just put the sticker div as a relative position in the inner div

http://jsfiddle.net/gisheri/pbev7sfm/2/